# How does reanimated Kakuzu use chakra?

Tags: naruto

How can Kakuzu use Chakra after he's reanimated if his Chakra network was permanently destroyed by Naruto's Rasenshuriken?

Comment: The way Edo Tensei is explained to work is that a living sacrifice and genetic material from a dead person create a vessel body, which is a copy the original body, for their soul to be summoned into. The specifics are blurry. For one thing it's implied that this body will always be heathy, except for the fact that Nagato is revived as a handicapped person. On the other hand Sasori is revived with the entire body and not as a jar of whatever he was at death. Kabuto says that he can tweak the vessel body to the point of Madara being revived in a young version of his body that never existed...